# Finding the two elements in a list that give the minimum absolute difference among all elements

Tags: python, list, difference, minimum

Let's say I have a list: `l=[7,2,20,9]` and I wan't to find the minimum absolute difference among all elements within (in this case it would be 9-7 = 2 or equivalently |7-9|). To do it in nlogn complexity, I need to do sort, take the difference, and find the minimum element:

```
import numpy as np
sorted_l = sorted(l) # sort list
diff_sorted = abs(np.diff(sorted_l)) # get absolute value differences
min_diff = min(diff_sorted) # get min element
```

However, after doing this, I need to track which elements were used in the original `l` list that gave rise to this difference. So for `l` the minimum difference is 2 and the output I need is 7 and 9 since 9-7 is 2. Is there a way to do this? `sorted` method ruins the order and it's hard to backtrack. Am I missing something obvious? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```py
index = diff_sorted.tolist().index(min_diff)
sorted_l[index:index+2]
```

##### Output

```
[7, 9]
```

##### Whole Script

```
import numpy as np
l=[12,24,36,35,7]
sorted_l = sorted(l)
diff_sorted = np.diff(sorted_l)
min_diff = min(diff_sorted)
index = diff_sorted.tolist().index(min_diff)
sorted_l[index:index+2]
```

##### Output

```
[35, 36]
```

##### Explanation

`tolist` is transforming the numpy array into a list whose functions contain a `index` which gives you the index of the input argument. Therefore, using `tolist` and `index` functions, we get the index of the minimum in the sorted array. Using this index, we get two numbers which resulted the minimum difference ([index:index+2] is selecting two number in the sorted array)

Comment: This doesn't work because you are hardcoding the index positions. I need something that can take any list as input and get the correct output. For instance, this won't work with the following list: `l2=[12,24,36,35,7]` output should be 35 and 36. with your code it its 12 and 24.

Comment: @Transcending The code is working fine, even in the case of your comment.(it returned [35,36]`). I add the whole code, in order to make it more clear for you.

Comment: Sorry typo on my end it worked. Could you explain the logic?

Comment: @Transcending Of course, I have added an explanation part to my answer as per your comment.